# HTML / CSS - Column content is showing from the bottom instead of top

Tags: html, css

I have this demo output: http://jsfiddle.net/uvqe14wL/

```css
.matching-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.matching-wrapper {
  height: 98vh;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.matching-wrapper .matching-product {
  display: inline-block;
}

.matching-product {
  width: 300px;
  height: inherit;
  margin-right: 15px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}

.matching-product.com-product {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="matching-wrapper">
  <div class="matching-product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="matching-product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="matching-product com-product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="matching-product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="matching-product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam accusamus pariatur laborum nam reprehenderit omnis animi illo consequatur deleniti, laboriosam sint. Aliquam enim possimus explicabo vitae impedit eveniet dolor deleniti.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, you can see that the first 2 columns content is showing from the bottom instead of top. I can not understand how can I fix it.

Comment: AHhhhh! I thinkg `vertical-align: bottom;` will fix this